# How to validate that input is an integer between two numbers in C++?

Tags: c++

I have something like this:

```
while (!(cin >> num) || (cin.get() != '\n')){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');  
}
```

but I can't figure out where to validate that the number is between the range of 1 and 10, without causing the program to hang.

Comment: Please share your attempt that caused the program to hang.

Comment: Why not after `.ignore()` `if (1 <= num && num <= 10) break;`?

Answer (score 1):

You can take an `std::string` and then use `std::stoi` to validate the input, as follows

```
int getIntInput(int from, int to) {

    std::string input;
    bool isValidInput = false;
    int validinput;

    while(!isValidInput) {
        try {
            std::cout << "\nPlease Enter a valid input between "<< from <<" and " << to <<":\t";
            std::cin >> input;

            size_t takenChars;
            validinput = std::stoi(input, &takenChars);
            if (validinput >= from && validinput <= to && takenChars == input.size()) isValidInput = true;
        } catch (...) {
        }
    }

    return validinput;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << getIntInput(-3, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input;
std::cin >> input;
if ("max" > input && input > "min")
{
//what you want to do 
}
else{
//error handling
}
```

Where max and min are the two numbers you have set as your boundaries.

Comment: `a > b > c` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. I suggest you delete this answer lest you'll earn downvotes.

Comment: @j6t I changed it, is it now correct?

Comment: No, still not correct. int and string literals cant be compared.

Comment: @S.M. Correct, and I never asserted that they are, maybe my documentation is a little faulty, but I explicitly said "Where max and min are the two numbers you have set as your boundaries.", it would be clear that OP is meant to replace "max" and "min" with his choice of numbers, e. 15 and 5.

Comment: There are other ways to make that clear.  Answering with code that actually compiles is one of them.