# validating if value enter is an integer

Tags: c++

First of all I am new to C++, can you guys help me with validating if value enter is an integer? And if my while statement in int(main) can be replace with a function.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int validateNumb (int numb, int lim){ 
//takes a num, limit and checks if number is within limit

    while (numb>=lim) {                                 //if outside limit
        cout << "Invalit input, try again with number (less than " << lim <<"): ";
        cin  >> numb;                                   //assign user input value
        
    }
    cout << "Your integer is: " << numb << "\n\n";      //display input value
    return numb;
}


int main() {
    
    //variables
    int num1, num2, num3, sum; 
    int limnum1, limnum2, limnum3;
    
    
    
    //Welcome message
    cout << "Hello & Welcome to E&M Ls1\n\n\n";                         
    
    //First Number
    cout << "Please Define the limit for First integer: ";
    while (!(cin >> limnum1))                           //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the First integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }
    cout << "Please Enter the First Integar that is (less than " << limnum1 << "): ";
    while (!(cin >> num1))                              //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the First integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }       
    num1 = validateNumb(num1, limnum1);                 //check condition
    
    
    //Second Number
    cout << "Please Define the limit for Second integer: ";
    while (!(cin >> limnum2))                           //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the Second integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }
    cout << "Please Enter the Second Integar that is (less than " << limnum2 << "): ";
    while (!(cin >> num2))                              //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the Second integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }               
    num2 = validateNumb(num2, limnum2);                 //check condition
    
    //Third Number
    cout << "Please Define the limit for Third integer: ";
    while (!(cin >> limnum3))                           //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the Third integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }
    cout << "Please Enter the Third Integar that is (less than " << limnum3 << "): ";
    while (!(cin >> num3))                              //if input is not true
    {
        cout << "Error!! Invalit input, please enter the Third integer: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
    }           
    num3 = validateNumb(num3, limnum3);                 //check condition
    
    //Sum for num1+num2+num3
    sum = num1+num2+num3;
    cout << "Sum of " << num1 <<" & " << num2 <<" & " << num3 <<" is: " << sum << "";   //display input value   
        cout<<"_______________________"<<endl;
        
        cout<<"Thank you & Goodbye"<<endl;      //end of the program 
            
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112347/how-to-validate-that-input-is-an-integer-between-two-numbers-in-c/64112459#64112459

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate that input is an integer between two numbers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112347/how-to-validate-that-input-is-an-integer-between-two-numbers-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

```
bool is_integer(float k)
{
  return std::floor(k) == k;
}
```

This solution should work for all possible values of k. I am pretty sure this is a case where you can safely compare floats using ==.
and yes your main can be broken into functions, maybe something like...

```
int getFirstNumber(){ 
int num =0; 
// copy your code to get the first number 
return num; 
}
int getSecondNumber(){ 
int num =0; 
// copy your code to get the second number 
return num; 
}
int getThirdNumber(){ 
int num =0; 
// copy your code to get the thirdnumber 
return num; 
}

int sum(int a,int b,int c){
return (a+b+c);
}

int main(){
int a,b,c,d =0;
a = getFirstNumber;
b = getSecondNumber;
c = getThirdNumber;
d = sum(a,b,c);

return 0;

}
```

EDIT: I see you want to check if the number is in a valid range...
here:

```
// Returns true if x is in range [low..high], else false 
bool inRange(unsigned low, unsigned high, unsigned x) 
{ 
    return  ((x-low) <= (high-low)); 
}
```